# Oracle pl/sql ORA-02204 error

Tags: oracle, plsql

With the following statement (attempting to grant a role permissions to use a view), I'm getting an error in Oracle:

```
grant execute on "PMC_TDT_V_APLICACION_EMAIL" to "PMC_TDT_ROL_USR";
```

Error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02204: privilegios ALTER, INDEX y EXECUTE no permitidos para las vistas
02204. 00000 -  "ALTER, INDEX and EXECUTE not allowed for views"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to grant or revoke an invalid privilege on a view.
*Action:   Do not attempt to grant or revoke any of ALTER, INDEX, or
           EXECUTE privileges on views.
```

Comment: What part of `"Do not attempt to grant or revoke any of ALTER, INDEX, or EXECUTE privileges on views"` did you not understand?

Comment: I answered my own question 2 days ago...  Simply to provide the number 1 site hit for this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a case of [RTFM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#i2126026) I'm afraid:

```
grant select on "PMC_TDT_V_APLICACION_EMAIL" to "PMC_TDT_ROL_USR";
```

We can only 'execute' Functions/Procedures, Views are handled like tables.